# Does Xcode post install supports relative path

Tags: xcode, post-install

ALL,

In the Xcode after the buid I'm executing the script that copies all libraries and resources into the Bundle.

However right now all path to the built libraries are hardcoded, like:

```
/Users/igor/<my_app>/Build/Products/Debug/<my_lib.dylib>
```

What I prefer is to use something like:

```
$BUILD_DIR/<my_lib.dylib>
```

Is it possible? Does Xcode supports something like?

TIA!!